# Content-Type header value missing after upgrade to WCF Data Services 5.0

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

After upgrading to WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData V3 i can't make insert or updates.
The only thing that is possible are selects.

**EDIT**

Exception in overridden method HandleException:

Exception:
System.Data.Services.DataServiceException: Content-Type header value missing.
   at System.Data.Services.HttpProcessUtility.ReadContentType(String contentType, String& mime, Encoding& encoding)
   at System.Data.Services.Serializers.Deserializer.CreateDeserializer(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService, Boolean update, UpdateTracker tracker)
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandlePostOperation(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessIncomingRequest(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description)
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()

ResponseStatusCode: 400

**Client-Code**
I set a token in the HTTP-Request-Header...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ServiceBase"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">service uri</param>
    protected ServiceBase(Uri uri)
    {
        this.Context = new Entities(uri) { MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges };
        this.Context.SendingRequest += new EventHandler<SendingRequestEventArgs>(this.ContextSendingRequest);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnSendingRequest
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">source</param>
    /// <param name="e">event args</param>
    private void ContextSendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.RequestHeaders["token"] = "xyassdfdfdfdf";
    }
```

**Service-Code:**
The Service parses this Header and checks the token

```
    public XYDataService()
    {
        this.ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += this.ProcessingPipelineProcessingRequest;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// OnProcessingRequest
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">source</param>
    /// <param name="e">event args</param>
    private void ProcessingPipelineProcessingRequest(object sender, DataServiceProcessingPipelineEventArgs e)
    {
        var authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["token"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader) || !authHeader.Equals("xyassdfdfdfdf"))
        {
            throw new DataServiceException(401, "401 Unauthorized");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Andi

Comment: Can you please describe the scenario in a little bit more detail? What client are you using? If possible can you grab a trace using Fiddler?

Comment: During SaveChanges i get the error. Selects are no problem. During Update or while adding new entries i get the error above. i am using the silverlight client. andi

Comment: Can you please post the exception along with the callstack? Also please use Fiddler and grab a trace of the request/response which fails.

Comment: var authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["token"]; this does not work when i comment this out it works. but i need to check a token set by the client?

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work", could you please be more specific and post the exception you're getting with a callstack and ideally a small piece of the code you're dealing with?

Comment: I've now updated my post and added source code, exception details, stacktrace, ...! Please help me in order to finish my upgrade! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please follow this post to get more descriptive error message from the server: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx? Possibly including the stack trace. If that doesn't work please attach a debugger to the service and capture the stack trace of the exception on which it's failing.

Comment: i have already set config.UseVerboseErrors = true and [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]? Thanks in advance

Comment: it seems that the error only appears during updating and inserting. It works fine for reading.

Comment: Can you please attach a debugger to the service and catch the exception thrown there and post the server side stack trace? (The client side stack trace is not that interesting in this case).

Comment: i am sorry but i don't know how to do that. Could you please describe that more?

Comment: Assuming you do own the server side, and assuming you're running it under IE or similar. Attach VS debugger to the server process. The easiest way to do this is to open the service project in VS, set it as startup project and Start it (usually F5). Then set the debugger to catch all exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E - CLR exceptions - stop on throw) and let it run. Then invoke your client and let it generate the error on the server. The debugger should stop on the exception.

Comment: Hi Vitek! Thanks for you reply but the server does not stop on the exception? andi

Comment: Can you verify that you set it up correctly by sending a bogus request, for example send a request to the service root with $filter=true? For example (against the sample service) http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc?$filter=true

Comment: Above the error code which only occurs when overriding the HandleException method in the data service class

Comment: Can you try to intercept the request with some tracer (for example Fiddler) to see if the content type header is actually present on the request?

Comment: hi vitek. here is a screenshot from fiddler during a update. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5xfwgsalfechl5/Error.PNG

Comment: if no token is set everything works fine. but i need the token for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Using answer since I need to put more text here.

I tried a very similar code to yours, but it works just fine:

```
DemoService ctx = new DemoService(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/(S(jcemln1vp0u1gqtoyqqpwrc1))/OData/OData.svc/"));
ctx.UsePostTunneling = true;
ctx.SendingRequest += (sender, ea) => { ea.RequestHeaders["token"] = "value"; };

ctx.UpdateObject(ctx.Products.First());
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Running this using the latest WCF DS 5.0 bits from NuGet works. I also verified with Fiddler that it does send the Content-Type header.

Your request on the other hand doesn't have the Content-Type header. Can you please verify that you're using the latest NuGet packages and that the code you posted above is really what you're testing?

Comment: hi vitek i am using the latest version 5.0.1. All works fine with the previous version 4.0

Comment: If possible could you please prepare a repro project and send it to me vitek.karas at microsoft com.